# Proxy settings ubuntu 15.10: proxy to no proxy switch

Tags: networking, apt, internet, proxy

At work, I need to use a proxy to get online. So, I go to the System>Preferences>Proxy settings and I fix the proxy manually.

Because I also wanted my package manager to connect to the internet, I went into

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d
```

and created a `95proxies` file containing these lines:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://13.1.1.3:3128";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://13.1.1.3:3128";
Acquire::socks::Proxy "socks://13.1.1.3:3128";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://13.1.1.3:3128";
```

(the numbers are just random)
after

```
sudo apt-get update
```

the package manager works fine.

But, now that I'm back at home, I turned off the proxy and mozilla connects fine, but the package manager cannot connect anymore. It still tries to connect through the proxy. I didn't have this issue in ubuntu 14.04. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? In other words how to make the direct internet connection work again?

Comment: Surprisingly, the out commenting worked. What didn't work is removing the 95proxies file.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help :). If you could please mark the answer bellow as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face a similar problem. What I normally do is that I simply comment out the content of that file(ie `95proxies`) and I'm good to go. In other words I am constantly commenting and un-commenting that file depending on where I am at. I wonder if there is a is a more elegant solution perhaps.